# How to get proper position of gripper for UR5 Arm?

Tags: ros, gazebo, urdf, ros-noetic

I am trying to attach gripper to ur5 arm but the gripper is not in proper position there must be origin changes.Does anyone knownhow to get gripper in a proper position? GRIPPER Should look proper like desired position. Can anyone help me with that ?

```
<!-- connect gripper to arm -->
  <joint name="robotiq_85_base_joint" type="fixed">
    <parent link="ee_link"/>
    <child link="gripper_robotiq_85_base_link"/>
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
  </joint>
  
   <!--################################################
  ########          Gripper                #####
  ####################################################-->
  
  <link name="gripper_robotiq_85_base_link">
      <visual>
        <geometry>
          <mesh filename="package://robotiq_description/meshes/visual/robotiq_85_base_link.dae"/>
        </geometry>
      </visual>
      <collision>
        <geometry>
          <mesh filename="package://robotiq_description/meshes/collision/robotiq_85_base_link.stl"/>
        </geometry>
      </collision>
      <inertial>
        <mass value="0.636951" />
        <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0" />
        <inertia ixx = "0.000380" ixy = "0.000000" ixz = "0.000000"
             iyx = "0.000000" iyy = "0.001110" iyz = "0.000000"
             izx = "0.000000" izy = "0.000000" izz = "0.001171" />
      </inertial>
    </link>

    <joint name="gripper_robotiq_85_left_knuckle_joint" type="revolute">
      <parent link="gripper_robotiq_85_base_link"/>
      <child link="gripper_robotiq_85_left_knuckle_link"/>
      <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
      <origin rpy="1.0 0.0 0.0" xyz="0.05490451627 0.03060114443 0.0"/>
      <limit lower="0.0" upper="0.80285" velocity="0.5" effort="1000"/>
    </joint>

    <joint name="gripper_robotiq_85_right_knuckle_joint" type="revolute">
      <parent link="gripper_robotiq_85_base_link"/>
      <child link="gripper_robotiq_85_right_knuckle_link"/>
      <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
      <origin rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0" xyz="0.05490451627 -0.03060114443 0.0"/>
      <limit lower="-3.14" upper="3.14" velocity="100.0" effort="1000"/>
      <mimic joint="gripper_robotiq_85_left_knuckle_joint"/>
    </joint>

    <link name="gripper_robotiq_85_left_knuckle_link">
      <visual>
        <geometry>
          <mesh filename="package://robotiq_description/meshes/visual/robotiq_85_knuckle_link.dae"/>
        </geometry>
      </visual>
      <collision>
        <geometry>
          <mesh filename="package://robotiq_description/meshes/collision/robotiq_85_knuckle_link.stl"/>
        </geometry>
      </collision>
      <inertial>
        <mass value="0.018491" />
        <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0" />
        <inertia ixx = "0.000009" ixy = "-0.000001" ixz = "0.000000"
             iyx = "-0.000001" iyy = "0.000001" iyz = "0.000000"
             izx = "0.000000" izy = "0.000000" izz = "0.000010" />
      </inertial>
    </link> 

    <link name="gripper_robotiq_85_right_knuckle_link">
      <visual>
        <geometry>
          <mesh filename="package://robotiq_description/meshes/visual/robotiq_85_knuckle_link.dae"/>
        </geometry>
      </visual>
      <collision>
        <geometry>
          <mesh filename="package://robotiq_description/meshes/collision/robotiq_85_knuckle_link.stl"/>
        </geometry>
      </collision>
      <inertial>
        <mass value="0.018491" />
        <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0" />
        <inertia ixx = "0.000009" ixy = "-0.000001" ixz = "0.000000"
             iyx = "-0.000001" iyy = "0.000001" iyz = "0.000000"
             izx = "0.000000" izy = "0.000000" izz = "0.000010" />
      </inertial>
    </link>

    <joint name="gripper_robotiq_85_left_finger_joint" type="fixed">
      <parent link="gripper_robotiq_85_left_knuckle_link"/>
      <child link="gripper_robotiq_85_left_finger_link"/>
      <origin xyz="-0.00408552455 -0.03148604435 0.0" rpy="0 0 0" />
    </joint>

    <joint name="gripper_robotiq_85_right_finger_joint" type="fixed">
      <parent link="gripper_robotiq_85_right_knuckle_link"/>
      <child link="gripper_robotiq_85_right_finger_link"/>
      <origin xyz="-0.00408552455 -0.03148604435 0.0" rpy="0 0 0" />
    </joint>

    <link name="gripper_robotiq_85_left_finger_link">
      <visual>
        <geometry>
          <mesh filename="package://robotiq_description/meshes/visual/robotiq_85_finger_link.dae"/>
        </geometry>
      </visual>
      <collision>
        <geometry>
          <mesh filename="package://robotiq_description/meshes/collision/robotiq_85_finger_link.stl"/>
        </geometry>
      </collision>
      <inertial>
        <mass value="0.027309" />
        <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0" />
        <inertia ixx = "0.000003" ixy = "-0.000002" ixz = "0.000000"
             iyx = "-0.000002" iyy = "0.000021" iyz = "0.000000"
             izx = "0.000000" izy = "0.000000" izz = "0.000020" />
      </inertial>
    </link> 

    <link name="gripper_robotiq_85_right_finger_link">
      <visual>
        <geometry>
          <mesh filename="package://robotiq_description/meshes/visual/robotiq_85_finger_link.dae"/>
        </geometry>
      </visual>
      <collision>
        <geometry>
          <mesh filename="package://robotiq_description/meshes/collision/robotiq_85_finger_link.stl"/>
        </geometry>
      </collision>
      <inertial>
        <mass value="0.027309" />
        <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0" />
        <inertia ixx = "0.000003" ixy = "-0.000002" ixz = "0.000000"
             iyx = "-0.000002" iyy = "0.000021" iyz = "0.000000"
             izx = "0.000000" izy = "0.000000" izz = "0.000020" />
      </inertial>
    </link> 

    <joint name="gripper_robotiq_85_left_inner_knuckle_joint" type="continuous">
      <parent link="gripper_robotiq_85_base_link"/>
      <child link="gripper_robotiq_85_left_inner_knuckle_link"/>
      <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
      <origin xyz="0.06142 0.0127 0" rpy="1 0.0 0.0" />
      <limit lower="-3.14" upper="3.14" velocity="100.0" effort="0.1"/>
      <mimic joint="gripper_robotiq_85_left_knuckle_joint" offset="0"/>
    </joint>

    <joint name="gripper_robotiq_85_right_inner_knuckle_joint" type="continuous">
      <parent link="gripper_robotiq_85_base_link"/>
      <child link="gripper_robotiq_85_right_inner_knuckle_link"/>
      <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
      <origin xyz="0.06142 -0.0127 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <limit lower="-3.14" upper="3.14" velocity="100.0" effort="0.1"/>
      <mimic joint="gripper_robotiq_85_left_knuckle_joint" offset="0"/>
    </joint>

    <link name="gripper_robotiq_85_left_inner_knuckle_link">
      <visual>
        <geometry>
          <mesh filename="package://robotiq_description/meshes/visual/robotiq_85_inner_knuckle_link.dae"/>
        </geometry>
      </visual>
      <collision>
        <geometry>
          <mesh filename="package://robotiq_description/meshes/collision/robotiq_85_inner_knuckle_link.stl"/>
        </geometry>
      </collision>
      <inertial>
        <mass value="0.029951" />
        <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0" />
        <inertia ixx = "0.000039" ixy = "0.000000" ixz = "0.000000"
             iyx = "0.000000" iyy = "0.000005" iyz = "0.000000"
             izx = "0.000000" izy = "0.000000" izz = "0.000035" />
      </inertial>
    </link>
    <link name="gripper_robotiq_85_right_inner_knuckle_link">
      <visual>
        <geometry>
          <mesh filename="package://robotiq_description/meshes/visual/robotiq_85_inner_knuckle_link.dae"/>
        </geometry>
      </visual>
      <collision>
        <geometry>
          <mesh filename="package://robotiq_description/meshes/collision/robotiq_85_inner_knuckle_link.stl"/>
        </geometry>
      </collision>
      <inertial>
        <mass value="0.029951" />
        <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0" />
        <inertia ixx = "0.000039" ixy = "0.000000" ixz = "0.000000"
             iyx = "0.000000" iyy = "0.000005" iyz = "0.000000"
             izx = "0.000000" izy = "0.000000" izz = "0.000035" />
      </inertial>
    </link>

    <joint name="gripper_robotiq_85_left_finger_tip_joint" type="continuous">
      <parent link="gripper_robotiq_85_left_inner_knuckle_link"/>
      <child link="gripper_robotiq_85_left_finger_tip_link"/>
      <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
      <origin xyz="0.04303959807 -0.03759940821 0.0" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
      <limit lower="-3.14" upper="3.14" velocity="100.0" effort="0.1"/>
      <mimic joint="gripper_robotiq_85_left_knuckle_joint" multiplier="-1"/>
    </joint>

    <joint name="gripper_robotiq_85_right_finger_tip_joint" type="continuous">
      <parent link="gripper_robotiq_85_right_inner_knuckle_link"/>
      <child link="gripper_robotiq_85_right_finger_tip_link"/>
      <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
      <origin rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0" xyz="0.04303959807 -0.03759940821  0.0"/>
      <limit lower="-3.14" upper="3.14" velocity="100.0" effort="0.1"/>
      <mimic joint="gripper_robotiq_85_left_knuckle_joint" multiplier="-1"/>
    </joint>


    <link name="gripper_robotiq_85_left_finger_tip_link">
      <visual>
        <geometry>
          <mesh filename="package://robotiq_description/meshes/visual/robotiq_85_finger_tip_link.dae"/>
        </geometry>
      </visual>
      <collision>
        <geometry>
          <mesh filename="package://robotiq_description/meshes/collision/robotiq_85_finger_tip_link.stl"/>
        </geometry>
      </collision>
      <inertial>
        <mass value="0.019555" />
        <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0" />
        <inertia ixx = "0.000002" ixy = "0.000000" ixz = "0.000000"
             iyx = "0.000000" iyy = "0.000005" iyz = "0.000000"
             izx = "0.000000" izy = "0.000000" izz = "0.000006" />
      </inertial>
    </link> 

    <link name="gripper_robotiq_85_right_finger_tip_link">
      <visual>
        <geometry>
          <mesh filename="package://robotiq_description/meshes/visual/robotiq_85_finger_tip_link.dae"/>
        </geometry>
      </visual>
      <collision>
        <geometry>
          <mesh filename="package://robotiq_description/meshes/collision/robotiq_85_finger_tip_link.stl"/>
        </geometry>
      </collision>
      <inertial>
        <mass value="0.019555" />
        <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0" />
        <inertia ixx = "0.000002" ixy = "0.000000" ixz = "0.000000"
             iyx = "0.000000" iyy = "0.000005" iyz = "0.000000"
             izx = "0.000000" izy = "0.000000" izz = "0.000006" />
      </inertial>
    </link>
    
    

  <!-- define the ur5's position and orientation in the world coordinate system -->
  <link name="world"/>
  <joint name="world_joint" type="fixed">
    <parent link="world"/>
    <child link="base_link"/>
    <!-- TODO: check base_link name of robot -->
    <origin rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0" xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
  </joint>
</robot>
```

Current Position
[image: Current Position]

Desired position
[image: Position]